# Dropdown List Option with Default Value that is not in the list

Tags: jquery, html

I am writing to ask is it possible to have a drop down list with a value pre-populated that is not in the actual list.

Say I have a system x that has a value y.  and they can only ever choose on the new system value a or b.  I would still like to display value y until they open the drop down at which point they loose it and it never comes back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<select>
  <option value="" selected="selected">show girl</option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
</select>
```

on click remove the option

```
$("select").click(function(){
$("option[selected='selected']",this).remove();
});
```

**UPDATE:**

as @fbfcn suggested in the comments it would be more appropriate to use `.one`

```
$("select").one("click",function(e){
$("option[selected='selected']",this).remove();
});
```

Comment: I would use .one() since the click event would only need to fire once.

Comment: This will remove each value that is selected after somebody change the selection.

Comment: @ParPar right after @fbfcn mentioned it i have updated the answer to use `one` so it is fired only once

Answer (score 0):

You can put a div on the dropdownlist with your wanted default value, then hide it when the user selects a value from the selectlist.

but fitst try this:

```
$("#yourdropdownlist").val("defaultvalue");
```